# JavaScript/jQuery find JSON key/value with partial match of variable and return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a list of models I want to search through and pull the url for the correct one. I won't always have the full key, and never the full value, but will always have at least a unique part of it.

Right now the code is just in test mode, with a set number that matches a key, print a success or failure.

The console keeps telling me that models[i].indexOf isn't a function. I know it's an object, but when I do a toString on it, I get "object Object". What am I not understanding?

I'm happy with a solution that is either vanilla JavaScript or uses jQuery.

The code:

```
if ($('.mobile_tutorial').length) {
    var device = /*$device.model*/ "NTZEZ717VLU", model_code = device.substr(2).substr(0,device.length-3);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/scripts/phone_models.json",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var models = data.Manufacturer;
            for (var i = models.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (models[i].indexOf(model_code) > -1) {
                    console.log(models[i])
                } else {
                    console.log('no match')
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The JSON (partial):

```
{
    "Manufacturer": [{
        "ZEZ955L": "http://x.com/mobile/home.seam?custId=ZEZ955L"
    }, {
        "ZEZ990G": "http://x.com/mobile/home.seam?custId=ZEZ990G"
    }, {
        "ZEZ828TL": "http://x.com/mobile/home.seam?custId=ZEZ828TL"
    }, {
        "ZEZ716BL": "http://x.com/mobile/home.seam?custId=ZEZ716BL"
    }, {
        "ZEZ717VL": "http://x.com/mobile/home.seam?custId=ZEZ717VL"
    }, {
        "ZEZ962BL": "http://x.com/mobile/home.seam?custId=ZEZ962BL"
    }, {
        "ZEZ963VL": "http://x.com/mobile/home.seam?custId=ZEZ963VL"
    }]
}
```

Comment: I originally misunderstood your question, please see my updated answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

models[i] is not a string so you are getting error. If you want to check key then use .each() function on models[i]. In that each loop compare the key using indexOf function.

```
if ($('.mobile_tutorial').length) {
var device = /*$device.model*/ "NTZEZ717VLU", model_code = device.substr(2).substr(0,device.length-3);
    $.ajax({
    url: "/scripts/phone_models.json",
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var models = data.Manufacturer;
        for (var i = models.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {


 $.each(models[i], function( key, value ) {
  if (key.indexOf(model_code) > -1)               {
                           console.log(models[i])
            } else {
                console.log('no match')
            }
        }
    }});               

});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to grab the value of the key changing `models[i].indexOf(model_code)` to `Object.keys(models[i])[0].indexOf(partial_model_code)`. Here's it in action:

```js
var partial_model_code = '3VL'

function ajax(data) {
  var models = data.Manufacturer;
  for (var i = models.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    
    // grab the keys in the object
    // since there will only be one object grab the first one
    // check if the key partially matches
    if (Object.keys(models[i])[0].indexOf(partial_model_code) > -1) {
      console.log(models[i])
    } else {
      console.log('no match')
    }
  }
}


var data = JSON.parse(`{
    "Manufacturer": [{
            "ZEZ955L": "http://x.com/mobile/home.seam?custId=ZEZ955L"
        }, {
            "ZEZ990G": "http://x.com/mobile/home.seam?custId=ZEZ990G"
        }, {
            "ZEZ828TL": "http://x.com/mobile/home.seam?custId=ZEZ828TL"
        }, {
            "ZEZ716BL": "http://x.com/mobile/home.seam?custId=ZEZ716BL"
        }, {
            "ZEZ717VL": "http://x.com/mobile/home.seam?custId=ZEZ717VL"
        }, {
            "ZEZ962BL": "http://x.com/mobile/home.seam?custId=ZEZ962BL"
        }, {
            "ZEZ963VL": "http://x.com/mobile/home.seam?custId=ZEZ963VL"
    }]
}`)

ajax(data)
```

I hope that helps!